# Openlayers 3: How to ensure map rendering

Tags: gis, openlayers-3

I have to build arrow features to show a velocity fields. The problem is that I load Point geometries with an external ajax function and I manipulate it to build a layer of Linestring before rendering the layer. The problem I have arises when I need to transform from pixel to geographical coordinates with the `getPixelFromCoordinate()` method. This happens and can be easily reproduced with the following code that only calls the method to transform the coordinates inmediately after the map object creation:

```
function init() {

  var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [ new ol.layer.Tile({ source: new ol.source.OSM() }) ],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({center: [0, 0], zoom: 2 })
  });

  var kk = map.getPixelFromCoordinate([0,0]);
  console.log(kk);
}
```

The return value is `null`. however if I force the map rendering before calling the transformation, the output is correct

```
map.renderSync();
var kk = map.getPixelFromCoordinate([0,0]);
console.log(kk);
```

In this case the output is correct:   `[500, 235]`
Can someone explain me if this is an expected behaviour and/or if there is an alternative way to do that ?, Thanks !

Comment: This is expected. Does it remain anything in this question?

Comment: Thanks !, I was wondering if there in an alternative way based on listening some map event fired at the rendering end. I was looking at "postrender" event with map.on('postrender'.... but when I tried I was not successful, although I was not sure if I made a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this event to the layer:

```
tileLayer.on('postcompose', function(e) {
    if (tileLayer.getVisible()) {
         var kk = map.getPixelFromCoordinate([0,0]);
         console.log(kk);   
    }
});
```